# Parallelizing calls to as.data.frame with parLapply

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a list of SDMXStructureSpecificData objects (see package `rsdmx`) that I want to transform into dataframes by simply using `as.data.frame`.

The following use of `lapply` works, but is quite slow:

```
# test data
library(rsdmx)
test_list <- list(readSDMX(providerId = "WBG_WITS", resource = "data",
                           flowRef = "DF_WITS_Tariff_TRAINS",
                           key = ".840.000..reported",
                           start = "2014", end = "2014",
                           headers = list(Accept = "application/vnd.sdmx.structurespecificdata+xml")),
                  readSDMX(providerId = "WBG_WITS", resource = "data",
                           flowRef = "DF_WITS_Tariff_TRAINS",
                           key = ".918.000..reported",
                           start = "2014", end = "2014",
                           headers = list(Accept = "application/vnd.sdmx.structurespecificdata+xml")))

# lapply
res <- lapply(test_list, as.data.frame)
```

I tried to use `parLapply` from the `parallel` package to speed up the process:

```
# parLapply
cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterExport(cl, "test_list")
res <- parLapply(cl, test_list, as.data.frame)
stopCluster(cl)
```

But even after exporting the list to the cluster, I always run into the same error: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  2 nodes produced errors; first error: argument of length 0`. Any advice?

Comment: You probably need to load the rsdmx package in your worker nodes

Comment: Like this? `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(rsdmx))` Still won't work...